# How to print out 2d array grid in vb.net console

Tags: arrays, vb.net, multidimensional-array

How would I print out a 2-dimensional array that is a grid 4 by 4 containing the values 1,2 and 3 for the first row and 1,2,3 for the first column? So far I have made my 2d array but I'm not sure how I would print this out to the console.

Here is the code I have done so far:

```
    Module Module1

    Dim OXGrid(3, 3) As String

    Sub Main()
        Initialise()
        Console.Read()

    End Sub

    Sub Initialise()

        Dim col, row As Integer

        'label the columns
        Console.WriteLine(OXGrid(0, 0) = "")

        For col = 1 To 3
            Console.WriteLine(OXGrid(0, col) = "" & col & "")
        Next
        'label the rows
        For row = 1 To 3
            Console.WriteLine(OXGrid(row, 0) = row & "")
        Next
        'initialise the grid 
        For row = 1 To 3
            For col = 1 To 3
                Console.WriteLine(OXGrid(row, col) = "")

            Next

        Next

    End Sub
End Module
```